# unable to read "/" on device

Tags: java, android, xml, xpath

I am processing an xml document and reading value from it. One of the value that am reading has / in it. This is how the value looks: `M/S John Smith At 4`. I was doing some testing on emulator and it was showing the correct value. Now i deployed my app to my `Samsung Galaxy S2 device` and the process is not reading the value correctly. It just shows M in the value field for that name.

I am thinking it could be because / is a special character. Is there something i can do to escape the special character in the value and read the whole name as it is?

P.S.: I am not an experienced Java Developer so this question may sound stupid to you but if you have the solution, please let me know.

When i am printing the value in console window, this is how it reads in the xmlDocument after parsing it: `M&#047;S John Smith At 4`

This function reads the value:

```
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
        Node child = e.getFirstChild();
        if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
          CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
          return cd.getData();
        }
        return "";
      }
```

In the adove function, `cd.getdata()` returns M

After some more debugging:

When i see the element in the watch window, for other names it has only one child. But for the element that contains / it got 3 children. It slices the stringbuffer bcz it sees / in there. I guess either i have to change the below function and ready all the child nodes or i have to use escape character in there before i pass it on.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting problem; can you post the code that you have written that is only extracting "M"?

Comment: the problem is, as you guessed, that '/' is a special character. The &#047; refers to the ascii value 47 of '/'. The twist here is that it works on the emulator, but not on the device, which is surprising, and I don't have a good answer for that. As far as simply getting it to work, you could try casting 'child' into a CDataSection (http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/CDATASection.html) rather than a CharacterData

Comment: It doesnt work. getFirstChild gives me first buffer so converting it to a CDATASection is not going to work.

Comment: Finally figured it out. e.getTextContent(); is what i shud be using. At least as of now it seems to give me the right result. :). Thank you for troubleshooting with me. Really appreciate your patience.

Comment: Yeah I don't know the specifics of how to elegantly handle the escaping of '/'. Although I don't totally understand the problem with converting to a CDataSection, since getFirstChild() returns a Node, and CDATASection is a subclass of Node?

edit: ah there you go then!

Comment: @Asdfg, feel free to write and accept your own answer, so others may also see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the new method now looks like:

```
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e) {
    return e.getTextContent();
  }
```

As of now this is working. I dont know for how long but hopefully till i decide to do the right thing and iterate over child nodes and concatenate the string values.

Answer (score 1):

If we're talking about a text node, have you tried `Node`'s `getNodeValue()`?

```
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e)
{
    Node child = e.getFirstChild();
    return child.getNodeValue();
}
```

Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeValue%28%29

Comment: Yes. I tried that. Same result. Bcz of / sign, that node has 3 children. I have to escape the / character, i think